# 7zip command line - cannot find code that works with archives

Tags: windows-server-2012, migration, compression

We are in the process of a server move, both to a new host and from a Server 2k8 box to a Server 2012 box.  The server in question has a few drives that hold our sites and some utilities.  These drives were duplicated exactly during the move.  Data, folder structures, and permissions should all be identical.

Recently, when running a Jenkins task on this server, I found the following in the log:

> G:\Websites\PathToWebsite>G:\Jenkins\Tools\7z a -tzip
>   Website_PROD_Backup_20140311_.zip
>
> 7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
>
> Error: 7-Zip cannot find the code that works with archives.

7-Zip is installed on the server and I can do the actions it's trying to do from the GUI.  I'm a developer and am not used to troubleshooting something like this, and Google for the specific error hasn't led me to any resolution.

The closest match I could find is a site that says the command-line tool needs a few .dll files if it's less than 150K.  I found the tool at the referenced path above and it was over 150K.  I copied the .dll files from the install directory to that directory anyway.  This did not fix the issue.

What should I do to fix this?  I really need 7-Zip to work from the command line or significant parts of our build/deploy process will have to be done by hand.

Comment: Is the build/deploy done via explicit scripts or by using a CI tool like TeamCity or CruiseControl.NET?  If it's run under a different user does the GUI work when running as that user?  Have you tried reinstalling the 7zip command line version? http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: @squillman: Build/Deploy is done via Jenkins using scripts.  Nothing in Jenkins has changed except the server it runs on (Web2, the new server, instead of Web).  I do not know what user it runs under.  Does installing 7-Zip install the command line version, or is that separate?

Comment: Ah, right.  Glossed over the Jenkins line...  7-zip command line is a separate install.  If it still doesn't work after installing the command line version find out what accounts the build tasks are running under.

Comment: @squillman: That seems to be fixing it.  I'm running a few of our scripts now to test.  Add that as an answer so I can give you a check :-)

Comment: Heh, glad it was that easy for you :)

Comment: @squillman: Sometimes it's the trivial stuff that takes longest to troubleshoot.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have the 7-zip command line version installed; it's separate from the GUI.  YOu can download it here:

[**http://www.7-zip.org/download.html**](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

Answer (score 5):

Another reason for this error is when you have 7z.exe but do not also have 7z.dll - both are needed for the commandline program to work properly.  Copying just these two files from the normal 7-zip GUI install folder is enough for a portable version of the commandline program on our CI.

Comment: This was my problem. I wanted to start 7z from cygwin and forgot to copy the .dll . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in Batch file set the path to the exe otherwise the batch Program will not know where the exe is located. if exe is at c:\Prog~1 files\bin\7zip.exe

set the path as c:\Prog~1 files\bin\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message as described above. Solved the problem by deleting the 7z.exe from the Windows\System32 directory (which was placed there by installing 7-zip as administrator?).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running '.\7z.exe' from a powershell script, the issue was that the .\ 'local folder' copy of 7z.exe was an older version than the one currently installed on my computer. To fix the issue I just copied the newer 7z.exe and 7z.dll files out to the local folder the script was using.